# display name of category based on parent id from the same table Laravel Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a mysql table named "category" that contains category_id parent_id category_name etc..
I want to display the name of parent_id from the same table 
how can I do it in my vue file with datatable ?

Comment: Can you please share the relevant code?

Comment: `headers:[
            {text:'ID', value:'category_id'},
            {text:'Category Name', value:'category_name'},
            {text:'Category description', value:'category_description'},
            {text:'Parent id',value:'parent_id'},
            { text: 'Actions', value: 'actions', sortable: false },

        ]`

Comment: `<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="categories"
    class="elevation-1"
    :search="search"
  >`

Comment: Edit your post to add your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be achieved by a number of ways.

SOLUTION 1:

The easiest that I can think of could be create a relationship on the `Category` model like:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Category';

    protected $primaryKey = 'category_id';

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(static::class, 'parent_id', 'category_id')
    }
}
```

Then from the controller:

```
use App\Category;

class CategoriesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return Category::with('parent')->get();
    }
}
```

Then your JSON response will be something like:

```
[
    {
        category_id,
        parent_id,
        category_name,
        parent: {
            category_id,
            parent_id,
            category_name,   
        }
    },
    {
        category_id,
        parent_id,
        category_name,
        parent: {
            category_id,
            parent_id,
            category_name,

        }

    }
]

// from the front-end you can access the parent name by:
category.parent.category_name
```

SOLUTION 2:

A more performant approach can be [adding a subquery](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#advanced-subqueries) like this:

```
class CategoriesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        Category::addSelect('parent_name' => DB::table('category as parent'))
            ->select('parent.category_name')
            ->whereColumn('parent.category_id', 'category.category_id')
            ->limit(1)
    }->get();
}
```

Then your JSON response will be something like:

```
[
    {
        category_id,
        parent_id,
        category_name,
        parent_name
    },
    {
        category_id,
        parent_id,
        category_name,
        parent_name
    }
]
```

Comment: Awesome @chaima! Pls make it the correct answer, other users might need that.